# Evaluating the indefinite integral $\int \frac{2x+3} {{x^2-2x-3}}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluating an indefinite integral it is simple.

Hello it is simple but I can not. Can you help me? evaluate the following integral:

$$\int \frac{2x+3} {{x^2-2x-3}}\mathrm{d}x$$

Give me show step by step solutions please.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $$\int\frac{2x+3}{x^2-2x-3}$$

$$=\int\frac{2x-2}{x^2-2x-3}dx+5\int\frac{1}{x^2-2x-3}dx$$

For integrate $\frac{2x-2}{x^2-2x-3}$ , substitute $t=x^2-2x-3$ and $dt=(2x-2)dx$:

$$=\int\frac{1}{t}dt+5\int\frac{1}{(x-1)^2-4}dx$$

For integrate $\frac{1}{(x-1)^2-4}$ , substitute $z=x-1$ and $dz=dx$:

$$\ln(t)+5\int\frac{1}{z^2-4}dz$$

Factor out $-4$ from the denominator and factor out constant:

$$=\ln(t)+\frac{5}{4}\int\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{4}}dz$$

For integrate $\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{4}}$ substitute $\varphi=\frac{z}{2}$ and $d\varphi=\frac{1}{2}dz$:

$$\ln(t)-\frac{5}{2}\int\frac{1}{1-\varphi ^2}d\varphi$$

The integral of $\frac{1}{1-\varphi ^2}$ is arctanh $(\varphi)$:

$\ln(t)-\frac{5}{2}$ arctanh $(\varphi)+\color{blue}c$

Substitute back for $\varphi=\frac{z}{2}$, $z=x-1$, $t=x^2-2x-3$:

$=\ln(x^2-2x-3)-\frac{5}{2}$ arctanh $(\frac{x-1}{2})+\color{blue}c$

Wich is equivalent for restricted $x$ values to:

$$\boxed{\color{red}{\frac{9}{4}\ln(3-x)-\frac{1}{4}\ln(x+1)}+\color{blue}c}$$

Comment: The last line is correct, but how did it come from the other lines? What happened to the arctangent in the previous line? Where did that arctangent come from? Why did you complete the square in the second integral when the denominator factors?

Comment: I can write all the details,it takes more time  :)

Comment: You need to check the derivative of arctanx. This is not the derivative of arctan.how you get it. Somothing wrong

Comment: Im working on a full answer

Comment: wtf this is your edit, are you joking with us?

Comment: didnt finished yet

Comment: it takes some time be patient

Comment: I have no idea how this got accepted in such a blatantly unfinished state.

Comment: This solution is also wrong. The integral of 1/(1-x^2) is not equal to tanx. The integral of 1/(1+x^2) is tanx.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadAsad The int of 1/(1-x^2) is arctan$\color{red}h(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\ln(x+1)-\ln(1-x))+c$

Comment: @Nehorai Sorry that's ok. Below there is an easy step to find integral of this question. You should check it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write $$\int \frac {2x-2+5}{x^2-2x-3} dx $$ and then integrate two integrals. The first is $\ ln|x^2-2x-3|+k$ and for the second integral ($\int \frac {5}{x^2-2x-3} dx$) use the coefficients $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\int \frac{2x+3} {{x^2-2x-3}}\mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\int \frac{2x-2} {{x^2-2x-3}}\mathrm{d}x+\int \frac{5} {{x^2-2x-3}}\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
I &= \int \frac{2x+3}{x^2-2x-3} \, dx = \int \frac{2(x-1)+5}{(x-1)^{2} - 4} \, dx
\end{align}
let $t = x-1$
\begin{align}
I &= \int \frac{2 t + 5}{t^{2} - 4} \, dt = \int \frac{2 t + 5}{(t-2)(t+2)} \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \, \int \left(\frac{2t+5}{t-2} - \frac{2t+5}{t+2}\right) \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \, \int \left( \frac{9}{t-2} - \frac{1}{t+2} \right) \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \, \left( 9 \, \ln(t-2) - \ln(t+2) \right) = \frac{1}{4} \, \left( 9 \, \ln(x-3) - \ln(x+1) \right). 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

As the given
$$\int\frac{2x+3}{x^2-2x-3}$$
$$=\int\frac{2x-2}{x^2-2x-3}dx+5\int\frac{1}{x^2-2x-3}dx$$
$$=\ln(x^2-2x-3)+5\int\frac{1}{(x-1)^2-4}$$
$$=\ln(x^2-2x-3)+5\int\frac{1}{(x-1)^2-(2)^2}$$
$$=\ln(x^2-2x-3)+5 \frac{1}{2(2)} \ln \frac{(x-1)-2}{(x-1)+2}$$
$$=\ln(x^2-2x-3)+ \frac{5}{4} \ln \frac{(x-3)}{(x+1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do the integral, but the most straightforward way, without tricks, uses partial fractions.

Your denominator is $x^2-2x-3=(x-3)(x+1)$. Therefore we look for constants $A$ and $B$ such that

$$\frac{2x+3}{(x-3)(x+1)}=\frac A{x-3}+\frac B{x+1}$$
$$2x+3=A(x+1)+B(x-3)$$

Substituting $x=-1$ into that gives us $-4B=1$ so $B=-\frac 14$; substituting $x=3$ gives us $4A=9$ so $A=\frac 94$. We can now easily do our integral.

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{2x+3}{(x-3)(x+1)}\,dx
 &= \int\left(\frac 94\cdot\frac 1{x-3}-\frac 14\cdot\frac 1{x+1}\right)\,dx \\
 &= \frac 94\int\frac 1{x-3}\,dx-\frac 14\int\frac 1{x+1}\,dx \\
 &= \frac 94\ln|x-3|-\frac 14\ln|x+1|+C
\end{align}$$

Note that the absolute value signs make this the most general answer to your integral, valid everywhere except $x=-1$ and $x=3$. As you probably know, the arbitrary constant $C$ could be different in the three intervals $(-\infty,-1), (-1,3),$ and $(3,\infty)$. That includes all the indefinite integrals for your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Hint : computational purpose only

$ \int \frac {px+q}{ax^2+bx+c}dx=\frac{p}{2a}log|{ax^2+bx+c}|+(q-\frac{pb}{2a})log|\frac{2ax+b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2ax+b+\sqrt{\Delta}}|$

> note: use this result only for $b^2-4ac>0$

```
In your problem
```

$a=1,b=-2,c=-3,p=2,q=3,\Delta=16$

$\int \frac {2x+3}{x^2-2x-3}dx$

$=\frac{2}{2(1)}log|x^2-2x-3|+(3-\frac{(2)(-2)}{2(1)})\frac{1}{\sqrt{16}}log|\frac{2x-2-\sqrt{16}}{2x-2+\sqrt{16}}|$

$=1log|x^2-2x-3|+\frac{5}{4}log|\frac{x-3}{x+1}|+c$

Where "c" is integral constant

Comment: In a quick mood I forget to type log term as first term shown in formulae

Comment: I just edited , you can now check that

Comment: Thank you Rory For your concern

Comment: If you like it please vote for my work